# What's the different between the solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have 2 solutions (see image below). This is how I create them:

1. File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET Web Application
2. File -> New -> Web Site -> ASP.NET Web Site

[image: 1. web application, 2. web site]

What's the different between the projects?

In Solution Explorer the only difference is the icon next to the project. They have the same file structure.

The question came up due to a problem I had with 2 solutions ([Doesn't recognize some labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208283/doesnt-recognize-some-labels))

Comment: Possibly.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application

Comment: possible to duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590501/difference-between-web-site-and-project-in-visual-studio

Comment: You answered my question but I have another one: Is there a way to have solution with multiple web sites? (I want to have a solution for practice and have in it multiple web sites for each subject I practice)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link you should read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx#summary_of_differences)

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)